# Bamboo "Run Docker Container" plugin strips credentials from "wait for service to start" URL

Tags: docker, bamboo

Bamboo version 6.7.1

My build starts a Spring-Boot REST service app inside of a Docker container, and attempts to run some tests against it.

I have configured the Docker start container plugin by selecting "wait for service to start" and in the URL field I have: http://username:password@localhost:{$docker.port}/actuator

When the container starts, I can access the service via cURLfrom the command line, using the same url from the plugin config. But Bamboo gets stuck waiting for the service to start, it never gets an OK from the service running in the container.

The Bamboo logs indicate the credentials are in the url being used and receiving 401 back from the service. But When I look at the logs generated by the service, I can see that every attempt to access the endpoint is anonymous, it seems the credentials are being stripped off of the URL after logging but before opening the connection.

Is this the expected behavior?

Bamboo logs:

> simple    09-Jan-2019 10:44:53    Attempting connection to http://username:password@localhost:8080/actuator
>   simple  09-Jan-2019 10:44:53    Failed connecting to http://username:password@localhost:8080/actuator returned status code 401, text: 
>   simple  09-Jan-2019 10:44:54    Attempting connection to http://username:password@localhost:8080/actuator
>   simple  09-Jan-2019 10:44:55    Failed connecting to http://username:password@localhost:8080/actuator returned status code 401, text: 
>   simple  09-Jan-2019 10:44:56    Attempting connection to http://username:password@localhost:8080/actuator
>   simple  09-Jan-2019 10:44:56    Failed connecting to http://username:password@localhost:8080/actuator returned status code 401, text:

The service logs indicate thousands of attempts to anonymously connect:

> 2019-01-09 16:26:21,250 - DEBUG - [http-nio-8080-exec-8] - [e83955c2f9a37521,e83955c2f9a37521,false] - o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@d016eb29: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@ffff8868: RemoteIpAddress: 172.17.0.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'

And then for each time I used cURL, a record indicating the authentication succeeded, so an HTTP 200 was returned:

> 2019-01-09 16:26:23,373 - DEBUG - [http-nio-8080-exec-1] - [41f2435ed5baaa5d,41f2435ed5baaa5d,false] - o.s.s.w.a.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter  : Authentication success: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@3e9aa9f7: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@9deba9f9: Username: actuator; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ACTUATOR; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@ffff8868: RemoteIpAddress: 172.17.0.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ACTUATOR